# Workaround for Bug Needed - Stop TableView small scroll when adding content to bottom of table

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `TableView` that has content added to it every 100ms or so, for about 5 or 10 minutes.

While that content is being added, if you aren't at the very top or very bottom of the table, the content scrolls a little bit each time an item is added.

Below is a very simple and runnable example of the problem.

Is there any way to get this table to stay still while content is added, without doing harm to the scrollability / usability otherwise?

**TableAutoScroll.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableAutoScroll extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {

        ObservableList<Person> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList( new ArrayList <Person>() );

        TableColumn <Person, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn <> ( "First Name" );
        TableColumn <Person, String> LastNameColumn = new TableColumn <> ( "Last Name" );
        TableColumn <Person, String> addressColumn = new TableColumn <> ( "Address" );

        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <Person, String>( "firstName" ) );
        LastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <Person, String>( "lastName" ) );
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory <Person, String>( "address" ) );

        TableView <Person> tableView = new TableView <> ();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll( firstNameColumn, LastNameColumn, addressColumn );
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );
        tableView.setItems( tableContent );

        for ( int k = 0; k < 500; k ++ ) {
            tableContent.add ( new Person ( "Dummy", "Person", k + " Sesame Street" ) );
        }

        tableView.scrollTo( 200 );

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane( tableView );
        stage.setScene( new Scene( pane, 800, 400 ) );
        stage.show();

        Thread populateThread = new Thread ( () -> {
            for ( int k = 0; k < 10000; k ++ ) {
                Person addMe = new Person ( "Dummy", "Person", k + " Sesame Street" );
                Platform.runLater( ()-> tableContent.add( addMe ) );
                try {
                    Thread.sleep( 100 );
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });

        populateThread.setDaemon ( true );
        populateThread.start();

    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        launch ( args );
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName, lastName, address;

    public Person ( String firstName, String lastName, String address ) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    } 

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug reported here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194328

Also had been reported here: https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8178297